# How do I boot the Ubuntu OS istalled on a 32GB USB drive?

Tags: 14.04, usb-drive, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 OS on a 32GB pendrive. But when I tried to boot from the USB drive, it goes into grub rescue mode. I am not talking about creating a bootable pendrive. I installed the Ubuntu OS on the 32GB pendrive, just like you would do it onto your hard disk. I am not able to boot into it. What do I do to boot into Ubuntu on the pendrive? Or how do I reinstall its grub?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS boot on flash drive? If BIOS this can probably fix it directly, not so sure if UEFI, but then post link to summary report it generates. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info UEFI requires gpt partitioning in advance and an ESP - efi system partition on your sdb or whatever flash drive is. And then manual copy of boot files from sda to sdb.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you used UNetbootin.

For whatever reason, people are always having problems with it.

I suggest this  alternative: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

If that fails too, have you verified the ISO's SHA-1?

Comment: I am not talking about a creating a bootable pendrive. I installed the "ubuntu OS" , on the 32GB pendrive, just like you would do it onto your hard disk. I am not able to boot into it.

Comment: @HariPrasad - That was not clear at all in your question. Please edit accordingly.